# Autofocus on mobile

Tags: forms, mobile, input-fields

The user is on a form only page. Does it makes sense to auto-focus the first field so that the keyboard automatically opens up.

On the desktop it makes 100% sense, but I am not sure if I need to do it on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on a Form only page, if the Form **only contains one field** to fill, that's the TextBox or EditText - Then, **Yes**, Feel free to Auto Focus and open up the Keyboard.

If there are **multiple fields** in your form, **do not auto-focus** until the user clicks on the field. This is important since that one tap makes him sure which field he is typing in, and he also gets to view the entire form before entering the Editing mode.

However, if you have two fields:

1. Username
2. Password

You can auto-focus on the Username first since almost everyone enters their Username before their Password. If the Username is already entered/detected, you can autofocus on the Password field.

It's generally a good idea to auto-focus if there are a limited number of fields having the same type of input. Else, not a good one.